ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : not able to redirect on custom login page after idle timeout/session timeout
I am working with ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project, where I set the idle timeout. I want to redirect to custom login page after idle timeout/session timeout, but it's not redirecting on custom login page, it's redirecting to the Identity account login page.
What I have written in program.cs file is:
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(builder.Configuration.GetValue<int>("MIGSettings:SessionTiming"));
    options.LoginPath = "/login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/login";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(builder.Configuration.GetValue<int>("MIGSettings:SessionTiming"));
    options.LoginPath = "/login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/login";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

When the session times out, I want to get redirected to
baseAddress/login 

and it's instead redirecting me to
baseAddress/Identity/Account/login


Hi @user24192006, how do you implement the User login to store the cookie/session? By default Identity or custom cookie authentication?

I am using by default Identity login, see below code:
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
